# Serializing cv::Mat with nlohmann/json lib

Tags: c++, json, opencv, nlohmann-json, opencv-mat

I would like to serialize my own Camera class with the nlohmann/json library:

```
class Camera
{
  private:
    std::string name_;
    std::string camera_calibration_filename_;
    cv::Mat intrinsics_;
    cv::Mat distortion_;

  public:
    Camera() = default;
    Camera(const std::string& name, const std::string& camera_calibration_filename);

    NLOHMANN_DEFINE_TYPE_INTRUSIVE(Camera, name_, camera_calibration_filename_, intrinsics_, distortion_)
}
```

As you can see i use the NLOHMANN_DEFINE_TYPE_INTRUSIVE macro to create a simple json with the same names. The intrinsics_ and distortion_ members have the third_party type cv::Mat. Therefore i have to specialize the adl_serializer in the nlohmann namespace:

```
namespace nlohmann {
    template<>
    struct adl_serializer<cv::Mat> {
        static void to_json(json &j, const cv::Mat &opt) {
            j = opt;
        }

        static void from_json(const json &j, cv::Mat &opt) {
            opt = j.get<cv::Mat>();
        }
    };
} // end namespace nlohmann
```

Since the cv::Mat type has members of type cv::MatSize, cv::MatStep i have to specialize adl_serializer for them. Since both data types are not copy-constructable but move-constructable i use the special from_json overload described in the documentation:

```
namespace nlohmann {
    template<>
    struct adl_serializer<cv::MatSize> {
        static void to_json(json &j, const cv::MatSize &opt) {
            j = opt;
        }

        static cv::MatSize from_json(const json &j) {
            return {j.get<cv::MatSize>()};
        }
    };

    template<>
    struct adl_serializer<cv::MatStep> {
        static void to_json(json &j, const cv::MatStep &opt) {
            j = opt;
        }

        static cv::MatStep from_json(const json &j) {
            return {j.get<cv::MatStep>()};
        }
    };
} // namespace nlohmann
```

But unfortunately the serialization/deserialization is not working correctely (Segmentation fault during serialization:

```
Camera camera{};
std::cout << "Camera initialized" << std::endl;

nlohmann::json j = camera;
std::cout << "Camera serialized" << std::endl;

auto camera2 = j.get<Camera>();
std::cout << "Camera deserialized" << std::endl;
```

Can anybody please give me a hint how to proceed?

Comment: Did you try to debug this using a debugger?

Comment: Hi Azeem, 
thanks for your answer. Yes, i tried to debug. The seg-fault appears here:
```
main.cpp: nlohmann::json j = camera;
```
```
camera.h: 
template<>
    struct adl_serializer<cv::Mat> {
        static void to_json(json &j, const cv::Mat &opt) {
            j = opt;
        }
```

Comment: Hi! Could you please add that debugging information? And, a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Comment: Ok, i will create a minimal, reproducible example ...

Answer (score 0):

this line makes a recursive call :

```
static void to_json(json &j, const cv::Mat &opt) {
     j = opt;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).